# Find a "Team" page using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For practice I've been learning Python and web scraping with BeautifulSoup. I'm looking to make a program that can find the Team page on a website and scrape the names of the team members. Here is an example of what a "Team" page looks like: http://plasticbank.org/team-speakers/

I've recognized that all team pages have "Team" noticeably bigger but not all sites use headers so its difficult to parse through them. I have gotten as far as loading a URL with urllib2. How would I go through a site's homepage and find a "Team" or really any page with a specific theme for that matter? It's the same kind of issue as finding a contact page, how do you tell the scraper to find it?

Here is the completed part of my code: (This just loads the site)

```
    #Pre: url is a string containing the address of a website
#return: A string with the URL formatted to include http://
def ensureurl(url):
    if '//' not in url:
        return "http://" + url
    else:
        return url

#Pre: url is a string containing the address of a website
#return: The HTML code at that URL or an empty string if the URL could not be processed
def read_url(url):
    url = ensureurl(url)
    print url

    try:
        #User agent spoofing to trick sites into thinking the bot is a human.
        #This does not work on all sites.
        hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
        request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)
        return urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.fp.read()
        return ""
```

Comment: Any code you've written?

Comment: I just edited the post to include the complete part of my code

Answer (score 0):

The scraper doesn't find stuff on its own - you need to describe the technical terms that define what you're looking for, which means that you'll have to set up some rules that will define what a 'Team' page is.

As a rule of thumb, to be able to use BeautifulSoup to identify something you should be able to identify it by looking at its HTML.

In your particular case, that's a pretty big task.
Maybe you can start with looking for a 'title' tag? That's where i'd go if i were you.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Assuming that the scraper can find "title" tags and recognize if its a "Team" section: What would you suggest I do in the event that the first page the scraper checks doesn't have a "Team" section?